# Speeding up GROUP BY, SUM and AVG queries

Tags: mysql, performance

The table arg_rec contains 800K rows on my test machine, normally this table will hold over 15M rows. I want to run the following query :

```
SELECT STE_ID, PNT_NO, YR, MN, AVG(AVR_WS) AS AVR_WS, SUM(AVR_PW) FROM arg_rec GROUP BY STE_ID, PNT_NO, YR, MN;
```

This query gives daily average wind speed and total power from wind turbine data. On my test machine this query times out after 10 minutes of execution with a combined index on `STE_ID`, `PNT_NO`, `YR`, `MN`, which is only a subset of the primary key columns. Without the index the query completes after several minutes.

I am running with pretty much a stock MySQL installation, in addition to tweaking the server I would also like to know more about other ways to handling this problem, such as :

1. Is it possible to create a view based on this query and cache the results ?
2. Are there more advanced indexing features to encapsulate the fact that YR, MN, DY, HR, MI, SC correspond to year, month, day etc field of the record timestamp ?
3. Am I better off just duplicating the data using the business layer of my application ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For best performance in GROUP BY queries you must add covering index as:

```
ALTER TABLE arg_rec ADD KEY ix1(STE_ID, PNT_NO, YR, MN,AVR_WS, AVR_PW );
```

For covering index you add:

1. columns used in where clauses first, then
2. columns used in group by, then
3. columns used in order by, and then
4. columns used in select.

Visit for details: [Group By Optmization in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html)

1. You can cache queries in MySQL by enabling query cache loot at [Query Cache Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html)
2. You can store YR, MN, DY, HR, MI, SC in a single column having data type as `TIMESTAMP` which will increase performance of indexing and group by operation.

Comment: By using the proper indexing dropped from 10 minutes to 0.7 seconds.

Comment: where do joins come in the order of things?

Comment: Join can be written alternatively as a where clause query. So joins comes first in terms of index sequence and then group by, order by, selected columns sequentially.